# GitLab clone initialization slow

Tags: git, gitlab

We have a ~ 150 MB repository on the local network on gitlab.

When cloning this one, it takes a long time before any downloading starts

Command:

```
git clone http://foobar.local/gitlab/foobar repo_deploy
Cloning into 'repo_deploy'...
```

**Nothing is happening now for around five minutes.**

```
remote: Counting objects: 35192, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (13552/13552), done.
remote: Total 35192 (delta 16644), reused 34647 (delta 16241)
Receiving objects: 100% (35192/35192), 125.49 MiB | 23.21 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (16644/16644), done.
```

What is happening during this time? How can we speed this up?

Comment: Is GitHub much faster for this size of repository? If not, there is likely nothing GitLab specific that could be done since GitHub has 230 employees vs 9 at GitLab and must have optimized this kind of thing to the limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cleanup you remote repository `git gc`

Documentation https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html

Source https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/XxqjX-JPRFg